# javascript no entra if

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código, para hacer una calculadora simple, selecciono los datos el tipo de operación, si las leo con un alerta por lo cual al menos el dato si llega pero no entra a ninguna de las opciones de mi ifelse para hacer las operaciones cual puede ser mi problema, si alguien puede ayudarme estoy haciendo mis inicios en javascript.

```
<br/><br/> 
Ingresa el Numero2
<br/>
<input id="num2" type="number"/>
<br/><br/>
Ingresa el tipo de calculo que quieres hacer:
</br>
(1)Suma (2) Resta 
</br>
(3) Multiplicacion (4)Division
<br/></br>
<input id="tipo" type="number" min='1' max='4'/>
</br></br>
<input type="button" value="Calcular el resrultado" onclick="calcula()"/><br/>
<div id="resultado">
<label id="Resultado">test</label>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function calcula(){

    var n1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var n2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
    let op = document.getElementById("tipo").value;
    var resultado;  

    alert(n1);
    alert(n2);
    alert(op);
    
    if (tipo == 1){
          resultado = numero1 + numero2
          tipo2 = "Suma";
       }else if (tipo == 2){
          resultado = numero1 - numero2;
          tipo2 = "Resta";
       }else if (tipo == 3){
          resultado = numero1 * numero2;
          tipo2 = "Multiplicacion"; 
       }else if (tipo == 4 ){
          resultado = numero1 / numero2;
          tipo2 = "Division";
       }     

          resultado = "El resultado :" + tipo2 + "es:" + resultado;
          document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = resultado;
}
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Así a ojímetro diria que te haces un lio descomunal con los nombres de variables, tanto las que pones en el HTML como después dentro del javascript.  Intenta uniformar correctamente esos nombres para que sean bien referenciados en todas partes, y luego, si aun no te sale, puedes [edit] la pregunta de nuevo con los cambios que has hecho. Es que ahora mismo peta por todas partes, no es un solo error, es todo mal, es decir, se ve demasiado descuidado para que te lo hagamos aqui, lo siento, suerte!

Comment: hola, no haz declarado la variable `tipo2` le pusiste `op`

Answer (score -1):

Estas declarando las variables n1, n2 y op en cambio estas usando en el if numero1 numero2.

Ten cuidado al declarar las variables!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form>
<br/><br/> 
Ingresa el Numero1
<br/>
<input id="num1" type="number"/>
<br/><br/>
Ingresa el Numero2
<br/>
<input id="num2" type="number"/>
<br/><br/>
Ingresa el tipo de calculo que quieres hacer:
</br>
(1)Suma (2) Resta 
</br>
(3) Multiplicacion (4)Division
<br/></br>
<input id="tipo" type="number" min='1' max='4'/>
</br></br>
<input type="button" value="Calcular el resrultado" onclick="calcula()"/><br/>
<div id="resultado">
<label id="Resultado">test</label>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function calcula(){

    var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value);
    var op = document.getElementById("tipo").value;
    var resultado;  
    var tipo2;

    alert(n1);
    alert(n2);
    alert(op);
    
    if (op == 1){
          resultado = n1 + n2;
          tipo2 = "Suma";
       }else if (op == 2){
          resultado = n1 - n2;
          tipo2 = "Resta";
       }else if (op == 3){
          resultado = n1 * n2;
          tipo2 = "Multiplicacion"; 
       }else if (op == 4 ){
          resultado = n1 / n2;
          tipo2 = "Division";
       }     

          resultado = "El resultado de la " + tipo2 + " es: " + resultado;
          document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = resultado;
}
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Te voy a recomendar este codigo de Javascript un poco mas directo, si tienes alguna duda te ayudare en los comentarios!

```
function calcula() {
   // parseInt() convierte los valores en numeros enteros
   const numero1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
   const numero2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
   const tipo = parseInt(document.getElementById("tipo").value);

   // Si es una suma
   if (tipo == 1) {
      escribirResultado(numero1 + numero2, "Suma")
   }

   // Si es una resta
   if (tipo == 2) {
      escribirResultado(numero1 - numero2, "Resta")
   }

   // Si es multiplicacion
   if (tipo == 3) {
      escribirResultado(numero1 * numero2, "Multiplicacion")
   }

   // Si es division
   if (tipo == 4) {
      escribirResultado(numero1 / numero2, "Division")
   }
}

function escribirResultado(resultado, tipo) {
   document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = "(" + tipo.toUpperCase() + ") El resultado es:" + resultado;
}
```